# SQL time in incorrect from that of my system timezone

Tags: sql, sql-server, timestamp-with-timezone

We have a SQL database that returns all the times in Greenwich Mean Time (GMT). We are in the Eastern Standard Timezone (EST). This messes up some queries that we have that pull data from specific dates. I tried using the (StartTime AT TIME ZONE 'Eastern Standard Time' as StartTime_ET, but that only returns the result as same in GMT -5. I just want the exact result to be in EST .

This changes the complete logic process of mine. Is there any way to do that?

Comment: By GMT, I *assume* you mean UTC? (As some people call the time in the UK GMT all year round, which is not the case). Or is your host actually observing UK time, and so would be BST (UTC+1) right now?

Comment: Hi Larnu, No, its in Greenwich Mean Time itself. We follow only the EST timezone all over. The system of mine and the app that sends data to db is also is in EST timezone.Hope that helps?

Comment: *"No, its in Greenwich Mean Time itself"* so UTC, as GMT is UTC+0.

Comment: Oh alright, is there anything I can do to convert?
My app settings shows as: TimeZone : (UTC-05:00) Eastern Time (US & Canada)

Comment: I've already posted an answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*Assuming* your values are all UTC and that your column `StartTime` is not a `datetimeoffset`, then you need to turn your value into a `datetimeoffset` first, and then change the time zone. When you use `AT TIMEZONE` on a date and time data type that *isn't* a `DATETIMEOFFSET` it is *assumed* that the value is already at the correct timezone. Therefore, for example something like `SELECT GETUTCDATE() AT TIME ZONE 'Eastern Standard Time';` would return `2021-08-05 09:53:56.8500000 -04:00` right now, even though the time in EST is actually `2021-08-05 05:53:56.8500000 -04:00` right now.

As a result you need to add the offset first and then use `AT TIME ZONE`. So, with `GETUTCDATE` that would be like this:

```sql
SELECT SWITCHOFFSET(GETUTCDATE(),0) AT TIME ZONE 'Eastern Standard Time';
```

Therefore, presumably, you just need to do the same for your column, `StartTime`, which is also a UTC time:

```sql
SWITCHOFFSET(StartTime,0) AT TIME ZONE 'Eastern Standard Time'
```

If you don't want the timezone portion, then you can convert it back to a different date and time data type:

```sql
CONVERT(datetime2(0),SWITCHOFFSET(StartTime,0) AT TIME ZONE 'Eastern Standard Time')
```

Comment: Sorry, but the result in coming in 'yyyy-MM-dd' format but I want that as same as system format, 'MM-dd-yyyy', is there any way for it?

Comment: @NishanthiSankar date and time data types don't have a format. Formatting is done in the presentation layer, not the RDBMS. It's up to your application to determine the format displayed.

Comment: I got it Larnu, but I am able to get the EST Time Zone when I do this query but I am also getting -4 In the side alone with Date and Time which affects when I import to my application

Comment: ... Read the whole answer @NishanthiSankar ... *"If you don't want the timezone portion, then you can convert it back to a different date and time data type:"* ... I've taken you to the water, but I can't force you to drink it; you need to do that yourself.

Comment: Can you not also use `StartTime AT TIME ZONE 'UTC'` instead of `SWITCHOFFSET(StartTime, 0)`

Comment: You can, @Charlieface, but `SWITCHOFFSET` is a little more succinct.